# My Netbeans RCP app fails when launched via the Netbeans-generated installer

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

My Netbeans RCP application compiles and works fine when started from the IDE (Netbeans 11/Win10).

If I start it using the Netbeans-generated installer, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor while loading org.openide.filesystems.FileSystem; see http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqTroubleshootClassNotFound
        at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.selfLoadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:238)
        at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:162)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.CLIOptions.cli(CLIOptions.java:134)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.CLIOptions.cli(CLIOptions.java:73)
        at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.notifyHandlers(CLIHandler.java:209)
        at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.initialize(CLIHandler.java:494)
        at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.initialize(CLIHandler.java:359)
        at org.netbeans.MainImpl.execute(MainImpl.java:168)
        at org.netbeans.MainImpl.main(MainImpl.java:60)
        at org.netbeans.Main.main(Main.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.netbeans.PatchByteCode.patchAsmMethod(PatchByteCode.java:161)
        at org.netbeans.PatchByteCode.apply(PatchByteCode.java:152)
        at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader.doLoadClass(JarClassLoader.java:226)
        at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.selfLoadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:234)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor starting from org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@31befd9f with possible defining loaders null and declared parents ]
        at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:199)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:197)
        ... 17 more
```

I tried with 2 different computers (Win10), with Netbeans 8 and Netbeans 11, same problem. My application uses Java 7.

I've checked http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqTroubleshootClassNotFound as mentioned in the error message but I found no "verify-class-linkage" issue when I build the app. I use only one external library using a Module library wrapper, and tested with the lib removed (using a code stub), problem is still there.

I have really no idea what to try to solve this... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found an explanation.

When Netbeans creates the distribution package the "asm-all-5.0.1.jar" is not copied in the "dist/myApp/platform/core" directory as it should be. Seems like a bug from Netbeans 8.1...

I can fix it manually in .zip distribution packages, but how to fix it in .exe installer ?

Comment: And now the "clean" fix : in my Netbeans project/properties/libraries, I removed the "Filesystems API 8.0 Compatibility" and "Execution API 8.Compatibility" modules from the Platform cluster, which were useless for my app.  Now the distribution packages run fine !